# How to use metaprogramming to create an enum in Perl 6?

Tags: metaprogramming, raku

Given data that represents an enum, such as:

```
my %enums := {
  Color => { red => 0, black => 1, green => 2 },
  Status => { fail => 0, pass => 1 }
};
```

How can I use `Metamodel::ClassHOW` to create enums equivalent to:

```
enum Color ( red => 0, black => 1, green => 2 );
enum Status ( fail => 0, pass => 1 );
```

Timo's ADT library gives an example of how to create a class with `ClassHOW`, but it doesn't cover enums: https://github.com/timo/ADT/blob/master/lib/ADT.pm6

Comment: It seems like it might be possible with the [`Metamodel::Primitives`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Metamodel::Primitives) class, but I don't know how. I'm going to research this a bit and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to do the trick, but it's mostly untested:

```
my %enums := {
  Color => { red => 0, black => 1, green => 2 },
  Status => { fail => 0, pass => 1 }
};
my @types = gather {
    for %enums.kv -> $name, %values {
        my $type = Metamodel::EnumHOW.new_type(:$name, base_type => Int);
        for %values -> $pair {
            $type.^add_enum_value($pair);
        }
        $type.^add_role(Enumeration);
        $type.^add_role(NumericEnumeration);
        $type.^compose;
        take $type;
    }
}.list;
say @types;     # Output: [(Status) (Color)]
```

Note that this puts the types into a data structure, because lexical scopes are immutable at run time, so you can't declare them just as you would with `enum Color ...`.

Comment: Thanks, moritz. When I create a type like that, I can't seem to access any of its data. I would expect `@types[0]::fail` and `@types[0].enums` to produce output, but neither does. Any thoughts?

Comment: @piojo I forgot to add the `Enumeration` and `NumericEnumeration` roles, see my updated answer. As for the symbol table access, it doesn't work like that for variables. You have to go through `@types[0].WHO` to access the symbol table.

Comment: Thanks again. I can't seem to access the symbols at all. I've tried `@types[0].WHO<fail>`, `@types[0].WHO::fail`, `@types[0]::fail`, `@types[0]^::.keys`, `@types[0].WHO.keys`, but I'm shooting in the dark. I'm getting the impression I'm better off just using hashes. If I've defined an enum type in container `$e`, is there any way to get a value for a key?

Comment: To get a value, you can use MOP once again: `@types[0].^enum_values<pass>` will give you a value by a key.